# JavaScript variable getting set to 0 confusingly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code that I've written that is supposed to keep track of which image is going to appear next on the page depending on which button is pressed

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#moveleft").click(function(){
                var negoff = "false";
                $("#slideshow>ul>li").animate({left: '-=' + actualwidth + 'px'}, 500);
                $("#slideshow>ul>li:first-child").remove();
                offset++;
                console.log("Offset: " + offset);
                if(offset > 4){
                    offset = 0;
                }
                if(offset < 0){
                    offset = offset * -1;
                    negoff = true;
                }
                $("#slideshow>ul").append('<li><img src="images/' + 
                    contentcategories[offset] + '.jpg"/></li>');
                $("#slideshow>ul>li:last-child").css({width: picturewidth +  "px", 
                    left: + 6 * actualwidth + "px"});
                if(negoff){
                    offset = offset * -1;
                    negoff = false;
                }
            });
            $("#moveright").click(function(){
                var posoff = "false";
                $("#slideshow>ul>li").animate({left: '+=' + actualwidth + 'px'}, 500);
                $("#slideshow>ul>li:last-child").remove();
                offset--;
                console.log("Offset: " + offset);
                if(offset < -4){
                    offset = 0;
                    console.log("Offset: " + offset);
                }
                if(offset > 0){
                    offset = offset * -1;
                    posoff=true;
                    console.log("Posoff: " + posoff);
                }
                $("#slideshow>ul").prepend('<li><img src="images/' + 
                    contentcategories[(contentnum - 1) + offset] + '.jpg"/></li>');
                $("#slideshow>ul>li:first-child").css({width: picturewidth +  "px", 
                    left: + 0 + "px"});
                if(posoff){
                    offset = offset * -1;
                    posoff = false;
                }
            });
        });
```

The confusing thing about this is that if I click on the #moveright button 2 times in a row the offset goes to -1 then to 0 and keeps looping through the 2 values. Nearly the same thing happens with the #moveleft button. It cycles through the values 0 and 1.

I am confused by this because the only place where I set the offset variable to 0 is if goes above 4 or goes below -4 and I'm not seeing a reason for it to be set to 0 after it goes to 2 or -2.

Comment: You'd better provide an realistic example on jsfiddle, because offset manipulation is quite messy in your code, it's hard to be confident for 100% what's going on.

Comment: There's a lot of redundancy between the two move functions. Delegate the event to the parent element, build just one move function to handle the click events and most likely the problem will solve itself.

Comment: Where is offset initialized in your code?

Comment: It was initalized globally at the beginning. The people who answered below are right I had "" around my initial variable declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at what you're doing here. You're writing a string into a variable, trying to use it as a boolean value, i. e. true and false, and then, in your if statements, you are checking whether or not the variable is: not null, not undefined, not false. The tricky thing here's that it actually is defined, it is not null, and it is a string ("false")

Long story short: Remove the "" around your "false", it should be fine then.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from `var negoff = "false";` and `var posoff = "false";`.

Your code could be refactored a bit but that's neither here nor there. The crux of the problem is that `"false" == true` since non-empty strings are truthy values in JavaScript. I assume it's just a typo, but here's what's happening:

`offset` starts at 0. If `#moveLeft` is clicked, it gets incremented to 1. Then it gets multiplied by -1 because `if(negoff)` will be true. So now it's -1 and the next click increments it back to 0. Rinse and repeat. The opposite is happening for `#moveRight`.